# Function that Stores the value from each iteration and then totals them

Tags: c++

So I am trying to write a program that takes the total cost of a set of books given a certain value and then loop back to the beginning in order to get the total of a new set of books until the user tells it to stop. At the end of the program a total of the total cost of all books will be displayed. I am stuck trying to write this, thanks for any help with this, and sorry for my messy code as I am still learning.

Code Listed Here:

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

const float kReqNew = 0.90;
const float kReqOld = 0.65;
const float kOptNew = 0.40;
const float kOptOld = 0.20;

class Book {

private: 
    float singleCost_;
    int NeworOld_;
    int ReqorOpt_;
    int TotalBooksNeeded_;
    int BookNumber_;
    int NumOnHand_;
    int prospectiveEnrole;
    double totalCost_;

public:
    void buildData();
    void determineBooks();
    void totalCosts();
    void layOut();
    void totalCostAdd();

};

void Book::buildData() {

    cout << "Please enter: " << endl;
    cout << "Book Number:";
    cin >> BookNumber_;
    cout << "Book Price: ";
    cin >> singleCost_;
    cout << "How many are in stock: ";
    cin >> NumOnHand_;
    cout << "Prospective Enrolment: ";
    cin >> prospectiveEnrole;
    cout << "Required(1), Optional(0)";
    cin >> ReqorOpt_;
    cout << "New(1), Old(0): ";
    cin >> NeworOld_;
}
void Book::determineBooks(){

    if(NeworOld_ == 1 && ReqorOpt_ == 1){

        TotalBooksNeeded_ = NumOnHand_ * kReqNew;
    }
    else if(NeworOld_ == 1 && ReqorOpt_ == 0){

        TotalBooksNeeded_ = NumOnHand_ * kOptNew;
    }
    else if(NeworOld_ == 0 && ReqorOpt_ == 1){

        TotalBooksNeeded_ = NumOnHand_ * kReqOld;
    }
    else if(NeworOld_ == 0 && ReqorOpt_ == 0){

        TotalBooksNeeded_ = NumOnHand_ * kOptOld;
    }
    cout << "Total Number of Books Needed: " << "$" << TotalBooksNeeded_ << endl;
}
void Book::totalCosts(){

    totalCost_ = TotalBooksNeeded_ * singleCost_;
    cout << "The total cost of the books is: " << totalCost_ << endl;

}

void Book::layOut(){

    cout << BookNumber_<<endl;
    cout << "$" << singleCost_ << endl;
    cout << NumOnHand_ << endl;

}

void Book::totalCostAdd(){

    double* newTotalCost;
    *newTotalCost += totalCost_;
    cout << newTotalCost << endl;
}   



int main() {
    Book books;
    int exitNum;
    cout << "\t\t\t ****************\n" << "\t\t\t  Book Calculator\n" << "\t\t\t ****************\n";
    do{
        cout << "*******************************************\n";
        books.buildData();
        cout << "*******************************************\n";
        books.layOut();
        cout << "*******************************************\n";
        books.determineBooks();
        books.totalCosts();
        cout << "*******************************************\n";
        cout << "Would you like to continue: Yes(1), No(0)" << endl;
        cin >> exitNum;
        cout << "*******************************************\n"; 
        books.totalCostAdd();

    } while(exitNum != 0); 
}
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: You're either going to need a running total variable that updates every iteration of the loop (ie a `double total_cost;` declared before the loop) or if you want to "*loop back to the beginning,*" you'll need a data structure to store all the books so you can loop over them at the end to calculate the total (and maybe other things too).

Comment: @scohe001 should probably be an answer

Comment: @JustinRandall Could be if I fledged it out a little more, but this has homework smell, so I don't want to give code or any more than the small hints I gave. Alone, I don't think those two hints make enough for an answer.

Comment: Hey, just wanted to say thank you for the help. I got the program to work.